# Regular expression to extract another expression from a string with delimiters

Tags: php, regex, routes

This question is a little odd, and I have spent a fair while pushing my knowledge of regular expressions to get this to the point it is at. I'm stuck at the last little bit however. The problem is as follows:

I have a string (which denotes a url in a routing system I'm modifying), that *may* contain a regular expression to match some segment. For example:

```
$pattern = "/some/path/to/</[a-z]+/>regex_var1/location";
```

The important bits to note here are:

- The regular expression is delimited within the string with `</` `/>` (this is not especially optional unless its the end of the world for legacy reasons. I would prefer to leave this as is).
- The bit of text after the `/>` (regex_var1) is a name for the match of this parameter. I need to keep this out of the expression to keep it compatible with the rest of the system, suffice to say it can be ignored in this context.
- This url pattern would match `/some/path/to/another/location`

What I want to achieve is to split a given format (example as above) into segments. These segments are used in a backtracking tree traversal to match a Request URI with a controller. At present regular expressions are not supported, my intention is to allow this. In the past each segment was denoted by a `/`, however I require `/` characters in the contained regular expression. If I use it in it's current form the expression is split across two segments. For example

```
$pattern = "/some/</([a-z]+)(/optional)?/>regex2/location";
$segments = preg_split('/(?<!<)\/(?!>)/', $pattern);
```

yields 4 segments

```
// print_r($segments)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => some
    [2] => </([a-z]+)(
    [3] => optional)?/>regex2
    [4] => location
)
```

when I actually only want 3

```
// print_r($segments)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => some
    [2] => </([a-z]+)(/optional)?/>regex2
    [3] => location
)
```

I am not interested in matching the whole URL with a regular expression, which would defeat the whole point of the exercise. This problem might seem unwarranted in isolation, but details about *why* I am after this specific implementation are beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I for one still don't understand exactly what you want. Can you give a real example and the output you actually want. I don't really understand what you mean with the `</` and `/>`

Comment: @Matt I have edited the original question, apologies if its still confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I cannot see an easy way to do it with a regexp only. You might first parse out the regexes (`/<\/.*?\/>[^\/]*/`), store them in an array and replace them by something easy yet non-clashing (`$1`), then run your regex and reinsert the regexes.

Comment: +1, I'd go as far as saying it is downright impossible to do this with a single `preg_split` call, that would require a variable length lookbehind which is not allowed on PHP.

Comment: @Adrian I ended up using a part of your answer, the parsing is done recursively so keeping a central stack of expressions was a little cumbersome. Thanks for your help, certainly got me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
$str = "/some/</([a-z]+)(/optional)?/>regex2/location";
$out_segments = array();
$in_regex = false;
foreach(preg_split('+/+', $str) as $segment) {
    if ($in_regex) {
        if (substr($segment, 0, 1) === '>') {
            $in_regex = false;
        }
        $out_segments[count($out_segments) - 1] .= "/$segment";
        continue;
    }
    if (!$in_regex && substr($segment, -1, 1) === '<') {
        $segment = substr($segment, 0, -1);
        if ($segment !== '') {
            $out_segments[] = $segment;
        }
        $in_regex = true;
        $segment = '<';
    }
    if ($segment !== '') {
        $out_segments[] = $segment;
    }
}
var_dump($out_segments);
```

**Edit:** The wrong pseudocode looked much easier. The idea is not that bad, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the string into its components first, and then processing it afterwards:

```
$url = '/some/location/</([a-z]+)(/optional)?/>regex2/here/or/there';
$reg = '#(.*?)(</.*?/>.*?(?=/|$))(.*)?#';
if( preg_match($reg, $url, $matches) ) {
    $result = array_merge(
        preg_split( '#/#', $matches[1], 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY),
        array( $matches[2] ),
        preg_split( '#/#', $matches[3], 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
    );
    print_r( $result );    
}

Array
(
    [0] => some
    [1] => location
    [2] => </([a-z]+)(/optional)?/>regex2
    [3] => here
    [4] => or
    [5] => there
)
```

The regex should always be in `$matches[2]`, so you can find it, no matter where it occurs in the URL.